# C# Array Merge Without Dupes

Tags: c#

Let's say I have these two arrays:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[2]{"Hello", "Stack"}
string[] arr2 = new string[2]{"Stack", "Overflow"}
```

How would I merge them to get a third array like so: `string[3]{"Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"}`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
string[] arr1 = new string[2]{"Hello", "Stack"};
string[] arr2 = new string[2] { "Stack", "Overflow" };

var arr3 = arr1.Union(arr2).ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: Note that this requires .NET 3.5 and LINQ.

Comment: @jrista - *strictly* speaking, not quite true. It could be any C# 3.0 compiler targetting .NET 2.0 with (for example) LINQBridge. No .NET 3.5 requirement. And if you roll your own extension method it could go anywhere, so there would be no mention of "LINQ", even in the `using` directives.

Comment: @Mark: Sure, *strictly* speaking. However, for the average .NET programmer, I think my statement holds true and is perfectly acceptable. (I think more people would upgrade to .NET 3.5 before they choose some third-party framework like LINQBridge or roll their own in-house framework...)

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] arr3 = arr1.Union(arr2).ToArray();
```

(if you have LINQ and a `using System.Linq;` directive)

Answer (score 0):

Old way of doing this

```
            List<string> temp = arr1.ToList<string>();
            foreach (string s in arr1)
            {
                if (!arr2.Contains(s))
                {
                    temp.Add(s);
                }
            }
            String[] arr3 = temp.ToArray<string>();
```

New and better way,  using .`Net Framework 3.5` + `LINQ`

```
  string[] arr3 = arr1.Union(arr2).ToArray();
```

Comment: For the "old way" `ToList` isn't available. Use `List<string> temp = new List<string>(arr1);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
ar2.Union<string>(ar1, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray<string>();
```